# CSS trick in place of javascript... almost working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

```
    <html>
    <style type="text/css">
    h3{
        display: block !important;
    }
    h3:active{
        display: block !important;
    }
    h3 span:before{
        content: "[-]";
    }
    h3:active span:before{
        content: "[+]";
    }
    div#summary:active >  h3, h3:active ~ h4, h3:active ~ ul{
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <div id="summary">
    <h3>Click to hide<span></span></h3>
    <ul><li>first</li></ul>
    <h4>title 1</h4>
    <ul><li>second</li></ul>
    <h4>title 2</h4>
    <ul><li>third</li></ul>
    <h4>title 3</h4>
    <ul><li>fourth</li></ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/BxrJz/

It works in chrome and firefox, but how do I get it to work in ie? Also, is there a way to make it stay in the hidden state until it is clicked again, so you don't have to hold it?

Comment: What is supposed to be happening?

Comment: I know that you can keep a link active by clicking and dragging your mouse off of the link and then releasing. Maybe if you changed the position of the active element or made it hidden too you could get the same effect... (and by the way that's pretty cool what you've got so far)

Comment: @JMC Creative - it's supposed to hide the h4 and ul elements

Comment: IE's support for CSS selectors is very poor, especially in IE6 where support is essentially non-existent. 7's somewhat better and 8's better still. 9'll probably have fairly complete support.

Comment: actually you can maintain that state if you expand the :hover element's size to cover the overall window (but AFAIK not outside - for example in the chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without javascript... CSS responds to events. It cannot change the DOM state permanently.

Comment: But a click can change the dom state for a link permanently to "visited". You used to be able to do some very neat stuff by exploiting this, see for example http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/experimenting-with-visited-links I think browsers have now disabled this functionality due to security concerns related to the "history disclosure hacks"

Answer (score 0):

This is some pretty cool css coding, but in terms of practicality, I would rethink the whole method you've used.  It's odd that one would click on the heading only, but not the [-] "button".  It only hides the text while the `<h3>` is in the active state, then the text reappears, and this is not intutive, not to mention practical.

If you are intent on researching this, google Stu Nicholls or Suckerfish for some css only hide/show behaviors. Learn from them, then adapt those to what you need. But as @Gaby said, CSS can't change the state of objects for good, only while the user is taking an action (like :hover or :active).

*As a side issue, I would add `cursor:pointer` to the `<h3>` and `<span>` tags so it's clearer that it's a clickable element.*

Comment: " Also, is there a way to make it stay in the hidden state until it is clicked again, so you don't have to hold it?" He said that in the question...